# Terraform Outputs across modules

Tags: variables, lambda, terraform

I am struggling to work out how to pass outputs from a module and to consume it an another.

My folder structure:

```
.
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   ├── cloudwatch-event
│   │   ├── basic_event_rule.tf
│   │   ├── basic_event_target.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── lambda
│       ├── basic_lambda.tf
│       ├── output.tf
│       ├── lambda.py
│       └── variables.tf
├── lambda
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variables.tf
└── terraform.tfvar
```

In order to add scheduling to the lambda, i need to consume the Lambda ARN in to the CloudWatch module.

The lambda - basic_lambda.tf

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
```

The lambda - outputs.tf

```
output "lambda_arn" {
  value = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda_function.arn}"
```

In my lambda application module, i have this in my main lambda/main.tf

```
module "cloudwatch-event" {
  source      = "../modules/cloudwatch-event"
  lambda_arn = "${module.lambda.lambda_arn}"

module "lambda" {
  source      = "../modules/lambda"
```

My lambda/variables.tf includes the lambda_arn variable as a string

```
variable "lambda_arn" {
  type = "string"
}
```

The root main file looks like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}
module "accesskey-lambda" {
  source = "./lambda/"
}
```

Running TF i get this

```
Error: Missing required argument

  on main.tf line 5, in module "accesskey-lambda":
  5: module "accesskey-lambda" {

The argument "lambda_arn" is required, but no definition was found.
```

then adding it to the root main file doesnt resolve my issues.

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i had a typo
in the cloudwatch/basic_event_target.tf

```
  arn   = "${var.lambda_arn}"
```

Then in the cloudwatch/variable

```
variable "lambda_arn" {
  type = string
}
```

The module then needed

```
module "cloudwatch-event" {
  source      = "../modules/cloudwatch-event"
  lambda_arn = "${module.lambda.lambda_arn}"
}
```